# ChangeNotifier Model - How to use fromMap()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class which extends `ChangeNotifier` like so

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Person extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _age = 0;

  int get age => _age;

  set age(int value) {
    _age = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> obj) => Person(
        age: obj["Age"],
      );
}
```

but get this error when adding `fromMap` method

```
The class 'Person' doesn't have a default constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'Person'.
```

Any idea how to correct this?

I did try

```
class Person extends ChangeNotifier {

  Person();

  int _age = 0;

  int get age => _age;

  set age(int value) {
    _age = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> obj) => Person(
        age: obj["Age"],
      );
}
```

but then get told

```
The named parameter 'age' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'age'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a named constructor that takes the age as argument.

```dart
class Person extends ChangeNotifier {

  int _age = 0;

  Person({int age}) : this._age = age;

  // Rest of your code
}
```

You can read more about Constructors here [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what this part is doing please? `Person({int age}) : this._age = age;` normally I would use `Person({this.age});`

Comment: @totalitarian You have no public member variable called age, you've a private variable _age. So you are introducing a local param/variable in `Person({int age})` you can put whatever param name there, like `Person({int foo})`. Then you want to assign the value you received in your local param to your private member.

Comment: @totalitarian I simplified the member variable assignment in a single line. It's same as writing `Person({int age}) { this._age = age;}`